# How can I convert a single-line array into a multi-line array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, regex

I'm trying to make something that picks a random word out of the english dictionary as a word for the game hangman. I found a good word list: http://www.mieliestronk.com/corncob_lowercase.txt and i've managed to convert it into an array. One problem though, it's an array on a single line and it's longer than 20k characters. If i try to copy paste the array into my project, it says that it's too long. So i wanted to convert it into a multi-line array. I've seen people use regexes but everytime i try it, it doesn't work at all... 
So, does anyone have a solution to my problem? Note: i've just started programming, so sorry if this question is really stupid or if i didn't explain it correctly.

Comment: A code beautifier should resolve the issue.  JS Beautifiers are designed to format JS code.

Comment: Why did you put it all on one line in the first place? You started with a multi-line file, just add quotes around each line and comma at the end, but don't remove the newlines.

Comment: I've tried 3 beautfiers now and none of them resolved the issue.

Comment: There are 58.000 words in that list. Doing it manually would be insane. I got the list from somewhere and the only thing i have to do is convert it into an array that isn't 20k characters long per line.

Comment: That text in your link looks to be separated by CRLF. What do you mean by single line. Does each line need quotes and a comma ?

Comment: Yes, i converted the whole list into an array but the whole array was on one line and visual studio code says it's too long. So I had to make it into an array that isn't on one line. Fortunately someone else linked me a good beautifier which resolved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would check out prettier https://prettier.io/, or another code formatter. This will get you started in formatting your code the way you want while you are developing.

Comment: Thank you very much, that beautifier resolved my problem.

Comment: Just know that it is incredibly opinionated, so customizing it to your liking is limited. If this answer is correct, please mark it as correct. 

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure what is the question tho

write this into the console

```
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('pre')[0].textContent.split(/\s+/));
```

you get an array that contains the words as values

Comment: I already got to the point where i had an array but it was on one single line an it's like 500k+ characters long. Visual studio code said that it was too long for one line. So i had to convert it into an aray that wasn't on one single line. Fortunately someone linked me a good beautfier which resolved my problem, but thanks anyways.